# Is there a formula to calculate the rents of properties in Monopoly boardgame?

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling

I'm writing a game of Monopoly for a personal project in a C++ class this semester and instead of hard-coding in each rent value of a property I was wondering if there's a formula to get them. For example, the first property (Mediterranean Ave.) has a base rent of \$2 with a rent of \$10 for 1 house which is 5x the base rent price. On the other hand the last property (Boardwalk) has a base rent of \$50 with a rent of \$200 for 1 house which is 4x base rent price.

I'm not very familiar with advance math, but I think I need something similar to a logistic function with a higher growth rate, then add 4 to it and I get a number between 4 and 5 that I would multiply by the base rent. Thanks for the help. $:)$

Comment: If I were doing this, I’d just have an XML data file that contains this and other game board data.

Comment: If I were doing this, I would have an array of stuctures with hard-coded initialisers. But to answer the OP's question: I don't think there is a mathematical formula that reproduces all the rents.

Comment: Ditto.  I doubt that a formula would be faster or smaller.  Certainly not enough to outweigh the simplicity of a table of some sort.

Comment: BTW you may be interested in an article in a very old issue of Mathematics Magazine (the "junior partner " of American Mathematical Monthly) on the results of a computerized Markhov-chain analysis of  Monopoly.